# SQL Query and OFType

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I did upgrade to EF 6, and I don't know how to migrate that situation, how to use `SQLQuery` and `OFType`?

```
//work - return more than 3000 registers
var a = db.AccountBase.OfType<Payable>()


//doesn't work - return 0 register
var a  = db.AccountBase.SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param, "AccountBase")).OfType<Payable>()
//not compile - ok
var a  = db.AccountBase.OfType<Payable>().SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param, "AccountBase"))
```

Comment: And what's the current code doing? Does it compile? Does it throw a runtime exception?

Comment: //just return 0 registers.
var a  = db.AccountBase.SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param, "AccountBase")).OfType<Payable>()

//not compile
var a  = db.AccountBase.OfType<Payable>().SqlQuery(Utils.Query(param, "AccountBase"))

Comment: I am thinking in change SQLQuery for public static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> Query<TElement, TValue>(Dictionary<string, string> values)